# Wordpress - custom fields plugin

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

Does anyone know a good custom field plugin for Wordpress that can do the following:

1. Add any type of custom field to a page, including additional wysiwyg editors.
2. Specify which specific pages the custom fields should show up on.
3. Option to remove the main wysiwyg and replace it with other fields.
4. Be simple to use.

This is all page oriented and not really for posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best one I've found that does all of this is:

http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/

Elliot has written some excellent plugins besides this one, check them out too :)

Comment: I tried that one but in my haste didn't realise how good it was! Just watched "how to" video, should be perfect!

Comment: It seems there may be a problem/bug with it. It works perfectly except for the one thing I want it to do!! On pages, I want certain fields to show up on some pages and different one's on others according to the template it's using (i.e products.php shows one lot of fields, page.php shows another). Except it's showing all the fields no matter what the template is.

Comment: Yep did http://support.plugins.elliotcondon.com/discussion/34/advanced-custom-fields-show-up-on-all-edit-pages cheers.

Comment: Haha, it's not you by any chance is it? Yep cheers for the help anyways.

Comment: I don't suppose anyone know's how to do the following do they? [list subpages and show custom fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459745/wordpress-show-subpages-and-their-custom-fields)

Comment: Haha no, no it isn't me. I just think the guy makes decent plugins.

Answer (score 1):

http://simple-fields.com/ is free and open source.

It has a easy to use interface but yet is extendable and let you for example use PHP to add field.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Bonzer Custom Fields Creator: 
**https://wordpress.org/plugins/bonzer-custom-fields/**

It creates wide array of input fields at various places inside the wordpress admin panel.
Places in the wordpress admin panel where custom fields are applicable includes:

- All Post Types
- All Taxonomies
- Pages:

  - Dashboard (Home)
  - Users (Your Profile)
  - Settings (All Pages)